Do I have meaningful information about the logic of the automated decision-making by all reputable data brokers?
From previous questions, GDPR Article 14, the requirement to inform the data subject after a data transfer has taken place, is generally fulfilled by ensuring the data subject has the data prior to the data transfer.  This is likely to involve an email with a link to a web site with this information.
The information required is quite extensive, and includes:


(g) the existence of automated decision-making, including profiling, referred to in Article 22(1) and (4) and, at least in those cases, meaningful information about the logic involved, as well as the significance and the envisaged consequences of such processing for the data subject.


Article 22(1) defines Automated individual decision-making as:

The data subject shall have the right not to be subject to a decision based solely on automated processing, including profiling, which produces legal effects concerning him or her or similarly significantly affects him or her.

If we extend the chain of events postulated in an answer to the above linked question:

You open a bank account.
The bank provides its own privacy notice per Art 13 GDPR.
The bank notifies you about Equifax' processing per Art 14 GDPR.
The bank sends data to Equifax, noting that they've already notified you.
You request a service that requires a credit check from Alice Inc.
Alice Inc. contacts Equifax which involves a transfer of personal data (name and address at a minimum) to Equifax
Equifax performs the decision-making process if(has been informed of bank account for that name and address) then (return "has bank account") else (return "has no bank account");
Equifax sends Alice Inc. this value
Alice Inc. offers the service at a certain price, or does not, depending on the returned result.

This must be a fairly common pattern, and it seems that if you do not have access to meaningful data about the logic performed by Equifax then someone is preaching the GDPR.  That someone could be Alice Inc. rather than Equifax.
From a quick google it is clear that there is some automated decision making going on.  Equifax are selling the tech to companies and companies are boasting about selling it to Equifax.  However I would not describe this as meaningful, it is certainly not actionable at an individual level.
While I have focused on Equifax, other companies that this could apply to include Cifas, MID, DVLA, Google ad marketplace, or any organisation that communicates personal data without direct human intervention.  A breach by any one would seem to expose all companies that rely on them to a potential data beach outside of their control.
Is some legally "meaningful" information public about the processing that happens at all these companies?  Is there some other exception being used here?  Or is every company that makes a credit reference enquiry in breach of the GDPR?

I challenge that Equifax is performing “automated individual-decision making”
In fact, as far as I can see, Equifax makes no decision about you at all. They receive a request, they provide a report. I've seen my Equifax report, indeed, I regularly review it.
Alice Inc uses that report to inform a decision they make. This should not be automated unless it falls into one of the exemptions. These include "When the decision is necessary for a contract" and "When the decision is based on the individual’s explicit consent", both of which are likely to be true for the situation you describe - you did read Alice Inc.'s terms and conditions, didn't you? You know, the ones where you explicitly gave consent?

In my example Equifax makes the decision to send "has bank account" or "has no bank account".  Also note the page you link is about when you can do automated individual-decision making, not when you need to tell the subject about it.

@User65535 that’s not a decision about you, it’s just the release of data.

How does challenging the specifics of the hypothetical answer the actual question? I submit that it does not.
